# Laravel 5.4 - Can't queue a mail

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason whenever I run

```
Mail::to($user)->queue(new WelcomeEmail($user))
```

it sends immediately instead of queuing it. I've already followed the [Driver Prerequsites](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#driver-prerequisites).

I tried to run it on `artisan tinker` and it still doesn't add to the queue.

This is my `WelcomeEmail` class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail\User;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Modules\User\User;

class WelcomeEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var Model
     */
    public $user;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->markdown('emails.user.registered');
    }
}
```

Is it because I'm running on a Windows machine?

Comment: which queue driver are you using?

Comment: @dparoli database

Comment: Just making sure, but in your `.env` file, what is the queue driver set to?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync`

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray I have changed it to `database`. Seems to work now. Thanks!

Comment: @EliyaCohen I've added an answer based on what you told me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment in the question, the trouble is that you have your `queue_driver` set to `SYNC` in your `.env` file. This "driver" will process everything immediately, this is useful when developping.

You need to set it to "database" if you want to use the database driver, or "redis" for the redis driver.